# Limit connected Clients - NodeJS

Tags: node.js

Given the follow HTTPS server:

```
var serverHTTPS = https.createServer(options, app).listen(9000);
```

How can I establish a limit of simultaneous connected clients?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [net#maxConnections](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_maxconnections). This property will limit your connections to whatever you set it too.

There's a caveat with using this though:

> Set this property to reject connections when the server's connection
>   count gets high.
>
> It is not recommended to use this option once a socket has been sent
>   to a child with child_process.fork().

Answer (score 1):

I personally would do that with a load balancer like HAProxy as shown in this blog article: http://blog.haproxy.com/2011/06/28/play_with_maxconn_avoid_server_slowness_or_crash/